# Kinetic energy distribution by mass in mass-spring harmonic oscillator system

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, vibrations

Basically I want to find a minimum working example of a non dissipative system that is able to concentrate kinetic energy on some subparts of the system.

My first guess was to use the coupled harmonic mass-spring system as described below:

[image]

I was expecting that a large mass $m_2>m_1$ would lead to $m_2$ being able to accumulate more kinetic energy over time even if periodically. It appeared that even though $m_2$ could reach a peak momentum higher than $m_1$ during an oscillation the peak kinetic energy for both was equal. I'm wondering if it is normal that peak kinetic energy is the same for both masses or if I made a mistake in the derivation. If the kinetic energy is bound to be the same for both masses can something be modified to allow localization of kinetic energy (like anharmonicity)? I'm expecting each $mode$ to reach the same kinetic energy but not each $mass$.

For a system with $k_1=k_2=K=1$ and $m_2=5m_1=5$, I get the $\omega_0=0.28$ and $\omega_1=2.12$ and the following egenvectors $a_0=\begin{pmatrix}0.99\\-0.11\end{pmatrix}A_0$ and $a_1=\begin{pmatrix}0.50\\0.86\end{pmatrix}A_1$. I get the values of $A_0$ and $A_1$ by imposing that the total energy of both modes is equal to 1. For example for $A_0$, we get $A_0$ and $A_1$ by solving:
$$\dfrac{1}{2} m_1 (0.99*\omega_0 A_0)^2 + \dfrac{1}{2} m_2 (-0.11*\omega_0A_0)^2 =1$$
$$\dfrac{1}{2} m_1 (0.50*\omega_1 A_1)^2 + \dfrac{1}{2} m_2 (0.86*\omega_1A_1)^2 =1$$
Once I've determined $A_0$ and $A_1$, I just plot the kinetic energy of both masses over time by:
$$E_{kin}[m_1](t) = \dfrac{1}{2}m_1(-0.99\omega_0A_0\sin(\omega_0t)-0.50\omega_1A_1 \sin(\omega_1t))^2$$
$$E_{kin}[m_2](t) = \dfrac{1}{2}m_2(-(-0.11)\omega_0A_0\sin(\omega_0t)-0.86\omega_1A_1 \sin(\omega_1t))^2$$
And plot both to get the graph below (orange dashed -- is $m_2$ and blue dash-dot -. is $m_1$) where basically for both masses a similar profile of kinetic energy is obtained

[image: Kinetic energy over time]

Here is the momentum

[image]

And here is the position.

[image]

So to sum up, I would be very grateful for feedback on:

1. Can kinetic energy be localized in coupled harmonic oscillators?
2. Does the derivation below show that it is not the case in this
   system?
3. Which would be simple system that exhibits kinetic energy
   localization?

Thank you very much for reading, I hope this is clear. 
Best Regards

Comment: What if you try $A_0=0.86$ and $A_1=0.11$? This way you start out with motion only in the lighter mass.

Comment: You mean setting initial conditions so that only the lighter mass has kinetic energy and see how it redistribute? Haven't tried that, it's true

Comment: Any progress? $ $